# ajax POST handler looping

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csrf

I'm trying to setup a basic ajax submit handler to modify a form (I'm writing a lesson on CSRF vulnerabilities), but the page keeps looping. Here's the example code I've been tinkering with, which is based off that from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

 <form id="hidden_form" target="blahblah.com"> </form>

 <script>
 //Attach a submit handler to the form
 $( '#hidden_form' ).submit(function( event ) {

      //stop form from submitting normally
      event.preventDefault();

      //set new target for the form
      var $form = $( this ),
        url = "http://192.168.101.250/mutillidae/index.php?page=add-to-your-blog.php&csrf-token=SecurityIsDisabled&blog_entry=example+text&add-to-your-blog-php-submit-button=Save+Blog+Entry"

      //capture the response but do nothing with it
      var posting = $.post( url );
 });
 </script>

 <script>
      $( '#hidden_form' ).submit();
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

When i load this file locally with my browser, the tab label switches between
/path/to/file.html and "Connecting" really fast, but I know the request never gets sent out because I have burp proxy intercepting all traffic and it's not capturing anything.

So what am I doing wrong? I want the ajax handler to send a POST request to the url specified, but it never gets sent out

EDIT: I've changed the second script to call the handler instead of the actual form, but there's still no traffic sent on the wire?

Comment: You didn't stop the default form submit from happening, so the page just keeps refreshing. (*Hint: HTMLFormElement.submit() bypasses jQuery bound submit events*)

Comment: does "event.preventDefautl()" not stop the default form from submitting?

Comment: It would, if that event handler was ever called.

Comment: thanks for the help, i have little to no experience with JQuery/Ajax, so how do I ensure that handler is called?

Answer (score 1):

Calling .submit() directly on the form element node does not trigger a submit event, instead, it directly submits the form bypassing all event handlers. You should instead call the jQuery form of the method which does trigger the event handler.

```
$( '#hidden_form' ).submit();
```